# Yocto - fetching repo from URL that contains spaces

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Yocto throws parsing error when it tries to fetch repo which contains `%20` encoded spaces in its URL.

```
BRANCH = "${SSC600_APP_BRANCH}"
GIT_URI = "gitsm://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/some-url%20bla%20bla"
GIT_PROTOCOL = "ssh"
```

Error message:

> ERROR: ssc600-app-1.4+gitAUTOINC-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'gitsm://ABB-BFA-ELDS@dev.azure.com/ABB-BFA-ELDS/**Multi-Feeder%20Protection%20Program**/_git/ssc600-client-node-modules;protocol=https;name=Work/Services/WebHMI/src/WebUI/ClientApp/node_modules;subpath=Work/Services/WebHMI/src/WebUI/ClientApp/node_modules;bareclone=1;nobranch=1'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
> ERROR: ssc600-app-1.4+gitAUTOINC-r0 do_fetch: gitsm: submodule download failed: FetchError Fetcher failure for URL: 'gitsm://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/ABB-BFA-ELDS/**Multi-Feeder Protection Program**/ssc600;protocol=ssh;name=ssc600;subpath=ssc600;bareclone=1;nobranch=1'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

As you can see Yocto parser replaces %20 with spaces in URL. How to get rid of this behavior?